# How to refactor this Ruby on Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, dry

I want to fetch posts based on their status, so I have this code inside my `PostsController` `index` action. It seems to be cluttering the index action, though, and I'm not sure it belongs here.

How could I make it more concise and where would I move it in my application so it doesn't clutter up my index action (if that is the correct thing to do)?

```
if params[:status].empty?
  status = 'active'
else
  status = ['active', 'deleted', 'commented'].include?(params[:status]) ? params[:status] : 'active'
end

case status
when 'active'
  #active posts are not marked as deleted and have no comments
  is_deleted = false
  comments_count_sign = "="
when 'deleted'
  #deleted posts are marked as deleted and have no comments
  is_deleted = true
  comments_count_sign = "="
when 'commented'
  #commented posts are not marked as deleted and do have comments
  is_deleted = false
  comments_count_sign = ">"
end

@posts = Post.find(:all, :conditions => ["is_deleted = ? and comments_count_sign #{comments_count_sign} 0", is_deleted])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :active, :conditions => { :is_deleted => false, :emails_count => 0 }
  named_scope :sent, :conditions => ["is_deleted = ? AND emails_count > 0", true]
  ...
end
```

use it like Post.active.all, Post.active.first, Post.active.each, etc

and then

```
status = %w'active deleted sent'.include?(params[:status]) : params[:status] : 'active'
@posts = Post.send(status).all
```

Answer (score 2):

I would consider adding a class method to Post

```
def file_all_based_on_status status

  # custom logic for queries based on the given status here
  # handling nils and other cases

end
```

That way your Controller index is simple

```
def index
  @posts = Post.find_all_based_on_status params[:status]
end
```

Comment: thanks! I think you meant `def find_all_based_on_status status` not `def file_all_based_on_status status`. Muscle memory at work.
Also, is there a way to make the find code itself more concise?

Comment: Make your finder method use named scopes like @zed_0xff's answer